# XSD.exe ignores simple complextypes

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, xsd.exe

We have a big wcf service, and a big xsd document where we have several elements and complex types. We generate code with the xsd.exe, and use the `XmlSerializerFormat` on our `ServiceContract` for the WCF service to serialize these objects again.

Now we have a problem with xsd.exe and the definitions of an array of strings.

Image we have the following element defined..

```
<xs:element name="Configuration" type="Configuration"/>
<xs:complexType name="Configuration">
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Parameters" type="Parameters" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Parameters">
     <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Parameter" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

which will result in:

```
 /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://mynamespace.com/")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://mynamespace.com/", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class Configuration {

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string Name;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Parameter", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
        public string[] Parameters;
    }
```

As you can see, the xsd.exe tool is smart enough to see the complextype `Parameters`, so it makes it a `string[]`.

The problem is, that if we use this in our WCF service, it will create `ArrayOfString` complextypes instead of our `Parameters` complex type. Even worse, we have several string[] resulting in `ArrayOfString1`, `ArrayOfString2`, `ArrayOfString3` and so forth..

The question is: How can we avoid that XSD flattens our `Parameters` complextype?

Comment: Its a xsd file, not a wsdl file ;), so wsdl.exe does not generate code..

Comment: you can try the xsd2code.codeplex.com which gives options like get lists instead of arrays and it may help you.