# Using our own xsd file in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd, wsdl, xsd.exe

We have a xsd file in which the contracts are already defined. We use `xsd.exe` to generate classes for our WCF service, and use the `XmlSerializerFormat` for our webservice again.

It seems to me, that this is a weird thing to do, to have WCF generate a new XSD for the classes which the `xsd.exe` generated for us, while we have already have our XSD definition right there for the taking..

While `xsd.exe` does a nice job of generating classes for us, it also simplifies complextypes as you can see in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761543/xsd-exe-ignores-simple-complextypes); meaning, the xsd actually changes a bit when it generates classes and are used in the webservice again; the ArrayOfStringXXX problem..

Can we tell the WCF service to use our own xsd file for its contract, instead of generating a new contract based on what the xsd.exe delivers?

What I tried:

- I already looked at this sample: [IWsdlExportExtension interface sample](http://winterdom.com/2006/09/asampleiwsdlexportextensionforwcf) which seems promosing, but I was not able to replace the xsd in the export method, because it was never 
  called.

**TL;DR: Can we point our WCF service to our own xsd file, instead of letting it generate it's own?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like [WSCF.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/) to generate the data contract classes from your XSD file.  I have experience from this and it works OK for most cases.  [See this blog for a good explanation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335699.aspx)

There are also other tools that enable this, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047161/contract-first-soa-with-wcf) for some suggestions.

There also seems to be a new option in Visual Studio 2012 for this, see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674270.aspx).  I haven't checked this out myself.

This development method is referred to as *contract first*, so you will find yet more info on Google :-)

Comment: I already tried WSCF.blue, and it also makes string[] instead of classes... Will look into the Contract-First tool!

Comment: It seems that the WCF options pane is only visible on "WCF Service Library" projects, NOT on "WCF Service Application".